# Using Supercapacitor Along With Battery

Tags: batteries, low-power, supercapacitor

[image: schematic]
[image]

The circuit seen in an existing meter

I am currently working on a smart meter solution(low power), where I am planning to add a supercapacitor to help the battery in supplying peak current surges without much drop in battery voltage. What all things should I consider when selecting the supercap? **Do I require additional circuits for this (than that in the schematic)?** How can I choose the supercap value, if I am using a 3.6V Li-ion battery (ER18505, Maximum recommended current under continuous discharge: 120mA) and the circuit can expect to draw a maximum surge current of 200mA?

When I was examining an existing smart meter, I could see the following circuit. Two supercaps of 1F in series along with the resistor and battery. How can we calculate the value of resistance, if we are using a different battery (different voltage, different ESR) and different supercap (different capacitance, different ESR)? Does the calculation involve ESRs of the supercap and the battery? Do anyone know how to calculate the resistance value for a given combination of supercap and battery?

But this question is meant to inform you about the practical results of the tests.

**Update ::**

*I calculated the supercapacitor value as per the basic capacitor current equation (calculations in the above question). It was around 1F. But when tested the actual circuit, it showed that even 20F is not sufficient. The voltage was 3V6 before the transmission. When load required the burst current, it was dip to 2V9 (where as per theoretical calculation only 0V1 dip was expected). Increasing the capacitor value gave better results, but not sufficient. We also tested the board with a 40F capacitor (LIC 0820).It gave some satisfactory result. But it is way higher than the calculated value. What might go wrong here? How can I select a suitable capacitor value ?*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98243/discussion-on-question-by-amalnath-satyan-using-supercapacitor-along-with-batter).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

Updating from new question's comments,

[image]

Image Source: http://ultran.ru/sites/default/files/catalog/svetodiody/brend/datasheets/er18505.pdf

You're ER18505 lithium cell looks to have an ESR of about 4 \$\Omega\$ for most of its discharge curve, , you're drawing surges up to 200mA for 100 milliseconds

Based on what you have given, you can expect a voltage droop of up to 4 \$\Omega\$ * 0.2A = 0.8V which is a problem as you want less than 0.3V, so now you need to smooth out that surge, which is going to be a right pain, I would strongly ask you to look at your design, and see if its possible to do more shorter connections?

OK simulator time, using a conventional capacitor with an ESR under 0.1 ohms, would need to be at least 56,000 uF.

This ends up being not as expensive as I first thought, but twice the diameter of your battery, even the leakage current is impressively small,
e.g. https://au.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Capacitors/_/N-5g7r?Keyword=56%2c000UF&FS=True

If we take it the other way and look at it being a 0.5 Farad super capacitor (capacitors in series divide in value) you would need less than 1.8 ohms ESR on the super capacitor, this seems much harder to accomplish,

Link to simulation: [Falstads Circuit Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000049999999999999996+25.510281670702206+50+5+43%0Av+112+224+112+128+0+0+40+3.5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+112+224+112+240+0%0Ar+112+128+176+128+0+4%0Ac+176+176+176+272+0+0.5+3.4110213033001484%0Ag+176+272+176+288+0%0Aw+176+128+320+128+0%0Aw+352+128+352+208+0%0AR+352+208+304+208+1+2+1+2.5+2.5+0+0.1%0A160+384+112+320+112+0+20+10000000000%0Ag+320+96+304+96+0%0Ai+384+112+384+224+0+0.2%0Ag+384+224+384+240+0%0Ar+176+176+176+128+0+1.8%0Ao+5+64+0+12546+3.460655361247465+0.0001+0+2+5+3%0A)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a capacitor bank will defintely help in sharing the peak current load, but super caps especially have **higher significant internal self discharge** and also **significant ESRs.**

Below sample datasheet is from [ELNA](http://www.elna.co.jp/en/capacitor/double_layer/catalog/pdf/dbj_e.pdf)
[image]

---

Here I have worked out a simple example to find the right value of the capacitance needed:

Requirements:
1. Voltage should not drop by 250 mV
2. Surge current expected is 200 mA
3. Duration of surge expected is less than 200 ms

with these inputs,

\$ Q =C\times V\$

\$ \frac{dQ}{dt} = C\times \frac{dV}{dt}\$

\$I = C\times \frac{dV}{dt}\$

in our case,
\$I = 200\, \mathrm{mA}\$,
\$dV = 250\, \mathrm{mV}\$,
\$dt = 200\, \mathrm{ms}\$,

solving, we get a value of \$250\, \mathrm{mF}\$ for the required capacitance. i would go with consideranble margin (even twice the value) with the value considering life time of the capacitor.

---

Many super capacitors also droop in the moment when the charging is stoppped( or when load is connected) and then recovers slowly. The ESR of super cap might limit its application in your case as you have a very good battery source which can actually support surge current more than you are looking for.

Comment: Is there anything have to be considered more in the circuit? Can I connect the supercap and battery as shown in the question figure? Is it required to have the ESRs of battery and supercap to be matched to get maximum efficiency?

Comment: Super caps provide good amount of energy in short amount of time. For a low power application like this, this might become a negative use case considering internal leakage (self discharge). What is the average current the MCU takes during sleep? I would reevaluate why micro controller stops working just below 3.3 V. What is the minimum operating voltage of the whole board, which particular component is blocking the operation upto 3 V for example?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the battery is ER18505, not 18650. ER18505 can only supply consant current of  100mA.

Comment: Please update about battery in the main Question as well. The calculations shoen above holds good still independent of the battery. Theoretically, capacitor alone can manage for such 200 ms duration with the permitted voltage drop. I will see about the battery

Comment: please see this thread too --> 
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/455902/227727